# Has Amazon been awarded this patent? (9,398,367)

Tags: amazon

Or just in general, what's the status of it? If I'm reading it correctly, it first filed for it in August 2014, and was granted it last week. Could be entirely wrong, though, so any help would be appreciated. Thanks guys.

http://patft.uspto.gov/netacgi/nph-Parser?Sect1=PTO2&Sect2=HITOFF&p=1&u=%2Fnetahtml%2FPTO%2Fsearch-bool.html&r=15&f=G&l=50&co1=AND&d=PTXT&s1=amazon.AANM.&OS=AANM/amazon&RS=AANM/amazon

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a granted patent to me.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's a granted patent. The patent has after its number the code "B1", which means that it is a granted patent that was never published as an application.

That's a little unusual, as most granted patent publications these days are code "B2". But the applicant requested that the patent application not be published after 18 months, so there was no publication as a patent application and thus this is B1 instead of B2.

If you want detailed information about this patent, sign into [Public Pair](http://portal.uspto.gov/external/portal/pair) on the USPTO website, search for the patent number, and you can find all the documents and other information that the PTO has.